# How to scale-out akka-jetty to multiple machines? (reverse proxy)

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka

I have a jetty (apache camel) Consumer akka actor which receives a request, routes the request along with the actorRef handle to the client socket to the proper "worker actor" to generate the requested content, then I send the content as a message back to the client actorRef.

The problem is that my program has become bandwidth-bound. Although akka is able to serve up the media without significant load, it has about 800mbps at peak which data starts to back up at the NIC and things start to fall apart.

I would like to expand my akka setup to multiple machines so that the data can be returned out through multiple machines (and therefore uplinks,NICs), however if I am correct, since the socket exists on the entry-point machine, sending the message to the client actorRef is going to route it back through the entry-point machine regardless of where the worker actors are. Is there any way to transfer the open socket to another server (I think this is called a reverse proxy) using TypeSafe's akka-camel implementation"? Google did not return anything helpful, but I feel like this is probably a common problem that needs to be solved so there must be a way.

Comment: Sounds like a clustering problem to me. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot transfer sockets between machines, because the TCP connection is established between two designated hosts. What you need to do is to run the service on multiple machines so that clients can connect to any of them, and then you can put a load balancer in front of them to offer a single IP to clients. Note that your load balancer then obviously needs at least a 10GB/s connection, otherwise you don’t win anything.